# EnableTransactionManagement cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

```
package com.shaun.spring.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.shaun.spring")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationContextConfig {

    // @Bean configurations go here...

}
```

i have a problem with  @EnableTransactionManagement
the following error that occurs is:EnableTransactionManagement cannot be resolved to a type.

i have the following dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

i have also tried using the following import:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
```

this gave me the following error:

```
The import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement cannot be resolved
```

Comment: What development environment (eclipse, IntelliJ, ...) are you using? (Its maven integration may be at fault)

Comment: @meriton i'm using eclipse

Comment: Then you might want to check whether the folder "Maven Dependencies" in your project view actually contains a spring-tx.jar, and whether that contains the EnableTransactionManagement class.

Comment: @meriton i have that jar but i dont seem to have the class in there.

Comment: According to [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-tx/4.1.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.java/), it should be there. Are you getting that artifact from the maven central repository, too? Either way, your maven doesn't appear to work right.

Comment: @meriton i just got the dependency code from: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx/4.1.6.RELEASE . What do you suggest i do?

Comment: That jar file contains org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.class, which you said your jar file doesn't.

Comment: @meriton it has that package but does not contain EnableTransactionManagement.class

Comment: I said the class was there because I have actually downloaded the jar file from the link you provided, unpacked it, and behold, the class was there. If your jar file does not contain the class, you have a different jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to just re add the jar file to the libraries in my project and the class was there. thanks for help meriton

Answer (score 6):

You are missing the `spring-orm` dependency for Object Relational Mapping.

Just import it into your pom file

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you develop in the `IntelliJ`, right click in the `POM` file and add as a `Maven` project. It should solve the issue.

Before
[image]

After 
[image]